# Windows 8.1 does not show ad hoc networks

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-8.1, ad-hoc-network

After upgrading my laptop to Windows 8.1, it no longer shows any ad-hoc networks to connect to. The networks are definitely detected by the hardware — [inSSIDer](http://www.metageek.net/support/downloads/) shows them, for example — but the Windows “connect to” interface shows only infrastructure networks. Ad-hockery worked on this computer under Windows Vista.

Comment: While written towards 8.0 it still applies to 8.1 http://www.eightforums.com/network-sharing/19109-help-how-create-ad-hoc-network-wifi-windows-8-a.html

Comment: @Ramhound I need to **join** an ad hoc network, not create one.

Comment: Shouldn't an ad-hoc network just appear as a wireless access point?  This thread has two possible solutions to the problem.

Comment: More information about the ad-hoc is required, and you need to finish your statement

Comment: The ad hoc network is created by ICS (Internet Connection Sharing) on a Vista computer.

Answer (score -1):

I'm actually using adhoc connection in windows 8.1 
you should type these command prompt lines to create it :

netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=NAME key=PASSWORD

netsh wlan start hostednetwork

(NAME is the name of the ad hoc network, you can change it...PASSWORD is your adhoc password, change it to a more secure one...)

To stop the adhoc network , type this command : netsh wlan stop hostednetwork

*(source : [How to share Internet to your Smartphone / Tablet ?](http://youtu.be/r_muaVZOwUk) )*

Comment: The network is created by ICS on a Vista computer